# The limit points of the disk $\{z \mid|z| < 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I'm having troubles proving that the complex numbers $x$ such that $|x|=1$ are the limit points of the complex open disk  $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| < 1\}$. I tried to consider the complex numbers $(x_{1}- \frac{1}{n}, x_{2}- \frac{1}{n})$ for such a $x$ but I'm not sure that these complex are in the disk in question.

Could you help me?

Comment: If you have $x\in\mathbb C,|z|=1$, why not consider $\lambda z$, for $\lambda\in(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: @StinkingBishop That idea looks interesting; could you give me more details?

Answer (score 3):

I'll denote by $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disc and $\partial\mathbb{D}$ its boundary (i.e. the unit circle).

Clearly every point of $\mathbb{D}$ is a limit point. Let $z'\in\partial\mathbb{D}$, and consider the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $z_n=(1-1/n)z'$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It's easy to check that this sequence converges to $z'$, and that each $z_n$ has $|z_n|<1$, so each $z_n\in\mathbb{D}$. This shows that $z'$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{D}$, and hence that $\partial\mathbb{D}$ is a subset of the limit points of $\mathbb{D}$.

Now for any $z'$ with $|z'|>1$, consider the open ball $B(z',|z'|-1)$. Check that this open ball has empty intersection with $\mathbb{D}$ - this suffices to show that the limit points of $\mathbb{D}$ are precisely $\mathbb{D}\cup\partial\mathbb{D}$.